# Excel Formula : how to set column A when column C = test123

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Column A, I want to change all blank columns to what I wish to input.

For an example, I want column D, anything that in the column D that is "hello", column A I will set to = model 1.

If column D = test123, I want to set all column in column A to model 2 when column D is equal to test123.

How do I do it? Anybody know what is the formula for that in Excel?

Please see the illustration below for better understanding of what am trying to ask.

Anyway, thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: It's a **column** (there's just one `l`)

Answer (score 1):

**Place this formula in Cell A2**

```
=IF(D2="test123","Model2",IF(D2="hello","Model1","Nothing matched"))
```